# Detect is string a file name or directory name

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I need to detect is my input string a file name or a directory name?
In my windows app I use this code:

```
    private bool IsFolder(string path)
    {
        return ((File.GetAttributes(path) & FileAttributes.Directory) == FileAttributes.Directory);
    }
```

but how can I do this check in Windows Phone 7? (7.1 if it's important)
Is any other way except check like this

```
if(storage.DirectoryExists(path)) return false; //and so on...
else ...
```

?

Thank you.

Comment: Well, if the name isn't a directory then you can assume it's a file.

Comment: Yes, that's clear for me. I just want to find some elegant way. May be some body gives me an advise.

Comment: Do not assume it is a file if the input string is not a directory.  The  input string could be neither a file nor a directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing special available to do this.
Just test if it's a file.
If not, test if it's a directory.
If not that, it's neither.